# python cmd.Cmd dynamically add a command

Tags: python, cmd

I am trying to build a cli framework where commands need to be added to dynamically. What I want to achieve is - I will have a minimum class which inherit from cmd.Cmd and later on I will write my commands in separate classes and load those commands along with main classes.

The following is what I tried but while trying to execute the command showmore, it throw TypeError

```
import cmd

class MyExtraCmds(cmd.Cmd):

  def do_showmore(self, *args):
    print (type(self))
    print ("Show more command")

class MyCmd(cmd.Cmd):

  def __init__(self, target=None, user=None, passwd=None):
    cmd.Cmd.__init__(self)

  def do_show(self, *args):
    print (type(self))
    print ("Show command")

  def do_EOF(self, line):
    return True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    setattr(  MyCmd, 'do_showmore', MyExtraCmds.do_showmore)
    print (dir(MyCmd))
    target = MyCmd()
    target.cmdloop()
```

Comment: You should include the traceback as well.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT 2:  I think you must be using Python 2, because in Python 3, this just works...

MyExtrasCommand is a different class, so this won't work, because for a normal InstanceMethod, the first parameter must be an instance of the class.

But Python classes *are* open; you can add to them later.  The easiest thing to do is start off with methods that are not currently in a class, and then they will be properly added to the class at run-time.  For example, this will work fine:

```
import cmd

def do_showmore(self, *args):
    print (type(self))
    print ("Show more command")

class MyCmd(cmd.Cmd):

    def __init__(self, target=None, user=None, passwd=None):
        cmd.Cmd.__init__(self)

    def do_show(self, *args):
        print (type(self))
        print ("Show command")

    def do_EOF(self, line):
        return True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    setattr(  MyCmd, 'do_showmore', do_showmore)
    print (dir(MyCmd))
    target = MyCmd()
    target.cmdloop()
```

If you print the type of MyCmd.do_showmore, you will see that your function has been properly wrapped into an InstanceMethod.

EDIT (for information only -- you probably *don't really* want to do this...)

Since everything in Python is open and inspectable, you *could* make your initial approach work by changing a single line.  The following will work in Python 2.7:

```
setattr(  MyCmd, 'do_showmore', MyExtraCmds.do_showmore.im_func)
```

For Python 2.7, adding `.im_func` to the end of this line says "grab the underlying function from the MyExtraCmds.do_showmore unbound method and use it."  I mention this because sometimes there are good reasons to use deep dark voodoo like this.  But your described use-case doesn't seem like it would fit in here, and it could be very confusing if, for example, you added additional class variables to `MyExtraCmds` and expected `do_showmore` to be able to access them.  The function that you strip out of `MyExtraCmds` and add into `MyCmd` will no longer have any knowledge of `MyExtraCmds` so that would be misleading and confusing.

Answer (score 1):

For me it works when I just set it with the equal operator. It does work as a valid command.

```
p = MyCmd()
p.do_extra = extra_command
p.cmdloop()
```

and I found a workaround to make it work for autocomplete and help.
Reimplement get_names() in your class (I don't know why they used self.**class** instead of self there)

```
class MyCmd(cmd.Cmd):
  def get_names(self):
    return dir(self)
```